Host Gatsby server less api function in docker using Nginx
I am currently trying to setup a docker container using nginx to host a Gatsby site. As that side is using a custom serverless function included in the gatsby directory at /api/function (working in development mode of Gatsby), this function needs to be injected/linked to the Gatsby Docker image.
That is the point where I am stuck right now.
Gatsby would expect the api to be available at
http://localhost/api/function

Does anyone have a suggestion, how to integrate the api function into the Docker image of the Gatsby site?
Best regards,
heyjoe
Dockerfile:
FROM node:22.9.0 AS base
ONBUILD RUN npm install -g gatsby-cli
ONBUILD WORKDIR /app
ONBUILD ADD . ./
ONBUILD RUN npm install --legacy-peer-deps

FROM base AS build
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:alpine AS final
COPY --from=build /app/public /pub
RUN apk --update add nginx bash && \
    rm -fR /var/cache/apk/*

COPY src/api/ ./api

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]

Nginx config:
[...]

 # Proxy API requests to the Node.js backend
location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/api;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
[...]

